# Почему меняется значение переменной в while (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, while

Почему значение переменной number1 меняется с продолжением работы цикла? Ведь console.log() - это всего лишь команда которая выводит что то на в консоль браузера , почему при выводе на консоль значения number1 , она еще и меняет само значение number1?

```
let number1 = 10
while (number1) console.log(number1--);
```

Comment: а ``number1--`` по-вашему что именно делает?

Comment: console.log выводит полученные данные. В него можно передавать функции и он вернет результат работы функции(если она что то возвращает). Одним словом, сначала происходит выполнение команд, затем выводится их результат. В вашем случае, console.log(number--) сначала выполняет операацию number-- , затем выводит результат.

Comment: Да , он вычитает 1 из значения number , но опять же console.log() - сама по себе ведь команда которая только выводит что то в консоль , он не должен менять саму переменную.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Консоль тут ни при чём. В программировании есть постфиксный инкремент/декремент и префиксный. Оба из них так или иначе увеличивают/уменьшают значение переменной. Вот так как тут применяется постфиксный оператор, то он и меняет значение